# Dynamic For loop (Count forwards or backwards)

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Hello I am trying to get my for loops to dynamically count either backwards or forwards. (to process positive to negative and negative to positive)

Below is my code, but it doesn't seem to function properly. (I don't understand how to change the for loop from +1 to -1 with a variable)

```
function _allbetween($coords1, $coords2) {
$blocks = "";

if ($coords2[0] == 0 || $coords2[1] == 0 || $coords2[2] == 0) {
    $temp2 = $coords2[0].",".$coords2[1].",".$coords2[2];
    $temp1 = $coords1[0].",".$coords1[1].",".$coords1[2];
    $coords1 = explode(",", $temp2);
    $coords2 = explode(",", $temp1);
}

for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
{
  if (substr($coords2[$i],0,1) == "-") { //if the value is negative
   $step[$i] = "--"; //substract the for loop
  } else { //else
   $step[$i] = "++"; //add the for loop
  }
}

for ($i1=$coords1[0]; $i1<=$coords2[0]; $i1.$step[0])
  {
        for ($i2=$coords1[1]; $i2<=$coords2[1]; $i2.$step[1])
            {
                for ($i3=$coords1[2]; $i3<=$coords2[2]; $i3.$step[2])
                    {
                        $blocks.= $i1.",".$i2.",".$i3."|";
                    }
            }
  }
return $blocks;
}
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do… Can you elaborate?

Comment: I am calculating all block locations between two points in a voxel based game, using two sets of coordinates. I was attempting to support negative values on the grid (-1,0,0) which in some other languages, required that the for loop be instructed to count backwards instead of forwards, however I discovered that php automatically calculates this.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind!

I see now that php automatically handles positive and negative values without changing ++ to --

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for this.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=2; ) // Note the removed $i++ here
{
  if (substr($coords2[$i],0,1) == "-") { //if the value is negative
   $i--; //$step[$i] = "--"; //substract the for loop
  } else { //else
   $i++; //$step[$i] = "++"; //add the for loop
  }
}
```

Comment: This works also, but as previously stated, this seems to be a little redundant, as php appears to automatically subtract the value if the second value is less than the first! Thanks for your contribution though!